# How to display the mobile gallery page in a custom view in android?

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
```

The above will take us to Gallery application which is there in our device,so we will be getting the Gallery screen which occupies the whole display of our device.But I want to display that Gallery application view in a Small Layout(something like I shown in below picture,instead of EditText,Buttons ,I want to get My device Gallery screen in that small layout).So that I can give user a feeling that he is not moving out of application.

I have seen this in one of the IPAD app (HelloAlbums).

IS it possible to achieve this in android?

I am using the above code to call phone gallery application.

But I want to display the gallery page in a custom view.[image]

Suppose like in a view which I used below.

How can I achieve this?

please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
public void ChoosePicture(View v) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
     {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
      {
        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        if (photoUri != null)
        {
        try {
              String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
              Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
              cursor.moveToFirst();
              int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
              String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
              cursor.close();
              bMap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
              ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
              img.setImageBitmap(bMap_image);


     }catch(Exception e)
      {}
      }
    }// resultCode
    }// case 1
    }// switch, request code
}
```

Comment: I have this code,before this I want to display gallery page in a custom view.